# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DecodeAuthorizationMessage operation:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sts

When trying to decode this message using: `aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message`, I get the following error.

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the
> DecodeAuthorizationMessage operation: User: (Blank) is not authorized
> to perform: sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage because no identity-based
> policy allows the sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage action.

I don't understand why this command is not working, I have also verified that the user has the inline policy to allow the decoding to happen as shown here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_DecodeAuthorizationMessage.html

Does anyone have any insight into why I might be running into this? I have verified I have no permission boundaries, or scp's that could be blocking this from being able to run. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `User: (Blank)` in the error message suggests to me that you have not aws cli configured properly.

Comment: I removed the string after user since it contains my name.